# how can i compare 2 variables without using ==

Tags: c++, compare

I need to write a c++ Projekt and the conditions are, i can only use the < to compare 2 variables. I cant use <=, >=, >, ==, !=. But now i need to compare 2 variables. How can i compare them, if they are the same without using ==.

Example:

```
 if {
A == B; // can´t use this but need to scan if they are the same
}
```

i have 0 idea how to do that so i hope any of you can help me.
I tried to do it like

A < B && B < A but i think i cant get to the solution.

Comment: Pop quiz: if the first variable is not less than the 2nd variable, and the 2nd variable is not less than the first one, then what conclusions can you draw from this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and OP, note, it's only valid if it's fully ordered. Some types are partially ordered and thus `!(A < B) && !(B < A) && !(A == B)` is still possible. E.g. nan, but there are other useful cases as well.

Comment: What is the type(s) of `A` and `B`?  If they are `float` or `double`, the answer is different than if they are `char` or `int`.  If you don't know, then the answer is "it depends".

Comment: `A < B && B < A ` can't possibly be true, since `A` and `B` can't both be less than the other. (Hint: "X is greater than or equal to Y" is equivalent to `X is not less than Y", and you *are* allowed to use negation.)

Comment: @molbdnilo in principle it can be `true` for some weird type, it would have rather useless `<` but its not impossible

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number And in principle, I could have been a famous actor in Hollywood.